# How can I describe various intermediary results of a percentage change calculation?

Tags: percentage

Lets say world happiness increases by 10%.

In one form of the calculation, I wind up with .1 and then I multiply that by 100 to get 10%.

In another form of the calculation, I wind up with 1.1, subtract 1 and multiply by 100.

What's the proper and least verbose way to describe the .1 and 1.1 intermediary results?  For example, an acceptable way to describe the 10% is "percentage change"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

0.1 and 10% are exactly the same thing just different representation. for 0.1 the scale is 0-1 for 10% the scale is 0-100. Both quantify the difference.
1.1 and 110% are also the same thing... they quantify the relative size.
Mathematically, all of that is exactly the same, they quantity happiness in 2016 with respect to happiness in 2015. It just depends how you want to present something.

From my experience all can be called change, growth, increase... etc. There is no good way to describe those numbers. The main difference in use is the actual value. More often people would report percent change if percent change is <1 (or ratio lower 2) and ratio else.

Exemple:
happiness is 10% higher in 2016 than in 2015. (10% percent change or ratio of 1.1)
happiness in 2016 is three times what it was in 2015. (200% percent change or ratio of 3)